# How to Mock getRecordNotifyChange

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

How exactly do we mock getRecordNotifyChange in a JEST test?  I cannot find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stub provided with lwc-jest for [uiRecordApi](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/blob/master/src/lightning-stubs/uiRecordApi/uiRecordApi.js) doesn't seem to include a mock function for that specifically so you'll have to create your own. Considering [getRecordNotifyChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_record_notify) returns void, you don't have to worry about any sort of expected result.

You can store it in a directory of `lwc/__tests__/lightning` and call it `uiRecordApi`. It'll be the same as the stub linked above except with an included mock function return for `getRecordNotifyChange`

```javascript
export const getRecordNotifyChange = jest.fn();
```

Then, you'll want to update `jest.config.js` to use your stub you created above for the `uiRecordApi` module. You'll add the relevant mapping under `moduleNameMapper`

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^lightning/uiRecordApi$':
        '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRecordApi
},
```

Then, in your jest test, just import the module (which'll use your stub from the mapping you created above)

```javascript
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from "lightning/uiRecordApi"
```